# Cypher don't reconnize gds function

Tags: cypher

i want to use gds.alpha.similarity.jaccard from https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/jaccard/, but cypher send a error

Code:

```
RETURN gds.alpha.similarity.jaccard([1,2,3], [1,2,4,5]) AS similarity
```

> Unknown function 'gds.alpha.similarity.jaccard' (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
> "RETURN gds.alpha.similarity.jaccard([1,2,3], [1,2,4,5]) AS similarity"

How can use jaccard ?

Comment: Have you installed the graph data science plugin? How?

Comment: how can i install it ?